# flowtype.js resulting in huge fonts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have followed the instructions to the letter on [flowtype demo](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/)
using steps 1 to 4.

When I display my page the fonts are huge. Using chrome on my PC which is 1920*1200, I have accessed the developer tools at full screen and looked at my `H1` element.

At the bottom of my inheritance for the `font-size` property is my `18px` from Step 1 of the instructions. Next I am getting a value of `40px` from something called the "user agent stylesheet" which I am assuming is the `flowtype.js` script. As per step 1 of the instructions I next have `H1` set at `4em` which results in the final size of `160px`!

I am calling the script using the recommendation in step 4. It is resizing everything as I resize my window but I cannot work out why it's starting with such huge fonts.

Comment: "_user agent stylesheet_" is the browsers built in default CSS settings.

Comment: Show your CSS please.

Comment: My CSS is as per the flowtype example website:/* the following is for the flowtype.js plugin */
body {
 font-size: 18px;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
 line-height: 1.45;
}
h1 { font-size: 4em; }
h2 { font-size: 3em; }
h3 { font-size: 2em; }
h4 { font-size: 1em; }

Comment: Strange how the "User agent stylesheet" is overriding my CSS above.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify the "basic" font-size in the `body`. Let's say: `body {font-size:12px;}`.

Code:

```
$('body').flowtype({
    minFont : 12,
    maxFont : 40,
    fontRatio: 30,
    minimum : 500,
    maximum : 1200
});
```

Specify the `minimum` width, the `maximum` width, the `minFont`, the `maxFont` and the `fontRatio`.
http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Comment: This is how I call flowtype:<script>
$('body').flowtype({
 minimum   : 500,
 maximum   : 1200,
 minFont   : 12,
 maxFont   : 40,
 fontRatio : 30
});

</script>

Comment: You also need to add the following CSS code: `body {font-size:12px;}`